# Mongodb collection objects total hours collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

mongodb collection data (thanks advance for this)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b3d78e95af70e17efd6d6"),
    "employeeId" : "2707",
    "employeeName" : "HrJosh",
    "status" : "Present",
    "date" : "2020-10-16",
    "clientName" : "Lorent",
    "projectName" : "ChatBot",
    "taskName" : "Learning",
    "durationHrs" : "09:30",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-05T15:36:24.677Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-05T15:36:24.677Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b5c3de95af70e17efd6d7"),
    "employeeId" : "2707",
    "employeeName" : "Gowdham",
    "status" : "Present",
    "date" : "2020-10-01",
    "clientName" : "Lorent",
    "projectName" : "ChatBot",
    "taskName" : "Meeting",
    "durationHrs" : "09:30",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-05T17:47:41.381Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-05T17:47:41.381Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b5c62e95af70e17efd6d8"),
    "employeeId" : "2707",
    "employeeName" : "Gowdham",
    "status" : "Present",
    "date" : "2020-10-02",
    "clientName" : "fsdsdsd",
    "projectName" : "ChatBotsd",
    "taskName" : "Manage Team",
    "durationHrs" : "09:30",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-05T17:48:18.994Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-05T17:48:18.994Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

we need output like total duration hours for calculate above three objects **durationHrs:((09:30)+(09:30)+(09:30))** ,
Output be like. **Total Duration Hour : 28hrs:30mins**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: {
         duration: {
            $toLong: {
               $dateFromParts: {
                  year: 1970,
                  hour: { $toInt: { $first: { $split: ["$durationHrs", ":"] } } },
                  minute: { $toInt: { $last: { $split: ["$durationHrs", ":"] } } },
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $group: { _id: null, durations: { $sum: "$duration" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         h: {
            $toInt: {
               $sum: [{
                  $multiply: [
                     { $dayOfYear: { $toDate: "$durations" } }, 24]
               },
               -24,
               { $hour: { $toDate: "$durations" } }]
            }
         },
         m: { $minute: { $toDate: "$durations" } }
      }
   },
   { $project: { durations: { $concat: [{ $toString: "$h" }, ":", { $toString: "$m" }] } } }
])
```

Be aware, it works only for duration's up to one year, i.e. 366 days.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you make `durationHrs` in your schema as Number field, and Store the number of minutes in it, that way it will be easy to calculate and sum all the fields using simple aggregation query.

But, if you cant change it, and want to get the answer using the current schema, you can try below aggregation, though i cant guarantee performance, it might be slow due to use of many aggregation stages and operators.

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      time: {
        $split: [
          "$durationHrs",
          ":"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      totalTime: {
        $sum: [
          {
            "$multiply": [
              {
                "$toInt": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$time",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              },
              60
            ]
          },
          {
            "$toInt": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$time",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      durationHrs: {
        $sum: "$totalTime"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      durationHrs: {
        "$concat": [
          {
            "$toString": {
              $toInt: {
                "$divide": [
                  "$durationHrs",
                  60
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          ":",
          {
            "$toString": {
              $mod: [
                "$durationHrs",
                60
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The summary of the aggregation pipeline is that, you split the durations, convert it into minutes, add the minutes and convert back into the desired format that you have.

The result will be :

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "durationHrs": "28:30"
  }
]
```

You can play with the query on [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aztdFgJ8Nx9)

You can read about all the operators used in the query in [official MongoDB docs.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i have to try that method . 1hrs.30mins store as 90mins in db after calculate then covert back as normal HH:MM this format im correct?

Comment: above you said method work-outed.  in collection i need specific employee total duration  hours. please check mongodb playground  https://mongoplayground.net/p/fXbFAe9LIVI

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$employeeId",
      totalduration: {
        $sum: "$durationHrs"
      },
      employeeId : {$first : "$employeeId"}
    }
  }
])` should work in that case