# MongoDB time Difference in hour and minutes

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents of following pattern

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f80656ce4e67b176f05fde5"),
    "owner" : ObjectId("5f120ba1578d051b20fb53e3"),
    "checkedInTime" : ISODate("2020-10-09T03:58:12.837-06:30"),
    "checkedOutTime" : ISODate("2020-10-09T07:12:10.906-06:30"),
    "punchIn" : true,
    "punchOut" : true,
    "isPresent" : true,
    "punchStatus" : false,
    "user" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f120ba1578d051b20fb53e3"),
        "emp_code" : 82140,
        "emp_firstname" : "rahul",
        "emp_secondname" : "narayanan unni",
        "emp_gender" : "Male",
        "dept_name" : "office",
        "avatar" : "src/assets/images/IMG-20180302-WA0025.jpg",
    }
}
```

I want a duration field which contain time difference(checkedOutTime-checkedInTime) in hours,minute,&seconds (i.e `hh:mm:ss, 12:10:03`),
how can i get this in mongodb.

```
db.getCollection('logs').aggregate([
{
         $project:{
              _id:0,
              In:"$checkedInTime",
              Out:"$checkedOutTime",
              Duration:{ 
                  $divide:[{$subtract: ["$checkedOutTime", "$checkedInTime"]},3600000]
                   /* i.e in hours,minute,&seconds (i.e hh:mm:ss, 12:10:03) */
              },
              Name : { $concat: [ "$user.emp_firstname","  ","$user.emp_secondname" ] }, 
              EmpCode:"$user.emp_code",
              Department:"$user.dept_name",
             }
       }
]}
```

new to mongodb please help, thank you

Comment: Better you project `$checkedOutTime` and `$checkedInTime`, and find the difference in server side and [`format it`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) using a library like moment

Comment: Thank you, @KunalMukherjee , as you said i used moment library to achieve the result, again thank you for your support

Comment: What happens when the duration is more than 24 hours ?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      Duration: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: {
            $dateFromParts: {
              year: 1970,
              millisecond: { $subtract: [ "$checkedOutTime", "$checkedInTime" ] }
            }
          },
          format: "%H:%M:%S"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Be aware, it works only for durations less than 24 hours. You could use `$dayOfYear` which will work for 366 days. However, you have to subtract 1 day, so some little coding is needed in this case.

Maybe have a look at this one: [Mongodb collection objects total hours collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250761/mongodb-collection-objects-total-hours-collection/64258693#64258693)

Comment: what happens if it overflows 12 hours ?

Comment: Nothing, as I have written it works up to 24 hours - otherwise just try it out.

Answer (score 1):

To span more than 24 hours you need to treat the HH:MM:SS as a duration format and not a strict time value.   To this end, we can simply treat HH as something between 0 and n and capture minutes and seconds as the divide-down remainders:

```
var hh = 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour                                                   

db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {"N": {$subtract: [ "$checkedOutTime", "$checkedInTime" ]} }},

{$addFields: {"H": { $divide: [ "$N", hh ]} }},
{$addFields: {"rH": { $floor: "$H" } }},

{$addFields: {"M": { $multiply: [ {$subtract:["$H","$rH"]}, 60 ] } }},
{$addFields: {"rM": { $floor: "$M" }}},

{$addFields: {"S": { $multiply: [ {$subtract:["$M","$rM"]}, 60 ] } }},
{$addFields: {"rS": { $floor: "$S" }}},
                      ]);
```

Given:

```
     "checkedInTime" :  ISODate("2020-10-09T03:58:12.837Z"),
     "checkedOutTime" : ISODate("2020-10-10T17:12:10.906Z") // note: over a day later...
```

we get:

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "N" : NumberLong(134038069),
    "H" : 37.232796944444445,
    "rH" : 37,
    "M" : 13.96781666666675,
    "rM" : 13,
    "S" : 58.06900000000496,
    "rS" : 58
}
```

To combine it all, condense, and format it as requested by the OP, try this:

```
ndb.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {"N": {$subtract: [ "$checkedOutTime", "$checkedInTime" ]} }},

{$addFields: {"H": { $divide: [ "$N", hh ]} }},
{$addFields: {"M": { $multiply: [ {$subtract:["$H", { $floor: "$H" } ]}, 60 ] } }},
{$addFields: {"S": { $multiply: [ {$subtract:["$M", { $floor: "$M"} ]}, 60 ] } }},

{$project: {"X": { $concat: [
               {$toString: {$floor: "$H"}},
               ":",
               {$toString: {$floor: "$M"}},
               ":",
               {$toString: {$floor: "$S"}} ]
                }}}
                      ]);
```